# Azure blob changes from private to public

Tags: azure, blob, private, public

I have created a private blob in a container on Azure.

Unfortunately it changes to public when I upload files. I have tried finding a way to set files as private when uploading, since that might be the problem, but I can't find anything.

Any ideas as to why this is?

Should private files be treated different when uploading?

My upload code:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

if (file != null)
{
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);

    blockBlob.Properties.ContentEncoding = MimeTypes.GetContentType(filename);
    if (ht != null)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in ht)
        {
            blockBlob.Metadata[item.Key.ToString()] = item.Value.ToString();
        }

        blockBlob.SetMetadata();
    }
    blockBlob.Metadata["Created"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    blockBlob.SetProperties();
 }
```

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: Your code looks all right to me. In fact, there's nothing in the code which performs operation on the blob container. Two things: 1) What do you mean what you say private blob? There's no such thing as a private blob. ACL (private/public) are applicable at container level. Are you seeing the container's ACL is changing from private to public? 2) Can you share the code for creating the blob container?

Comment: My bad. I have a container that is private and that changes to public when I upload a file (at least it changes at some point).

I created the containter in the Azure management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems allright, please take a look here:

[How to use Blobs in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs-20/?fb=nl-nl#create-container)

Your blob will get the same access permissions as your container.

Some extra information: It seems you using StorageClient Library v1.7. This one is deprecated, v3.0 is the recommended version ([StorageClient Library v3.0.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495001%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)).

There is an [issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx) in the StorageClient Library v.3.0.0 using containers on your local (test) machine though.

Comment: Found the error. It was my bad. When copy/pasting the following code sneaked in:

container.SetPermissions(
                new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });